# Can't access Object properties within object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

You guys didn't like my last question so I'm trying to be more clear.

I have an object called result and it is an array of 100:

[image]

```
{
"id":2,
"name":null,
"description":null,
"tableName":null,
"displayId":0,
"itemNameFieldId":0,
"itemPkFieldId":0,
"dropDownInd":false,
"items":null,
"itemAttrs":null,
"updatedItems":null,
"updatedGpi":[
  {
  "GPI":"11000010002105",
  "THER_CLASS_DESC":"Amphotericin B For Inj 50 MG",
  "GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"
  },
  {
  "GPI":"11000010101910",
  "THER_CLASS_DESC":"Amphotericin B Cholesteryl Sulfate Complex For Inj 50 MG",
  "GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"
  },
  {
  "GPI":"11000010101920",
  "THER_CLASS_DESC":"Amphotericin B Cholesteryl Sulfate Complex For Inj 100 MG",
  "GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"
  },
  {
  "GPI":"11000010301820",
  "THER_CLASS_DESC":"Amphotericin B Lipid Inj Susp (For IV Infusion) 5 MG/ML","GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"},{"GPI":"11000010401920","THER_CLASS_DESC":"Amphotericin B Liposome IV For Susp 50 MG","GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"},{"GPI":"11000020000105","THER_CLASS_DESC":"Flucytosine Cap 250 MG","GENERIC_NAME":"*Antifungals**"},{"GPI":"11000020000110","THER_CLASS_DESC":"Flucytosine Cap 500 MG","GENERIC_NAME"[…]
```

I converted to JSON for clarity. As you can see there is an array called UpdatedGPI.

When you open that array it has 100 objects.

I am trying to iterate though them bit it just errors out:

> (Error: result.UpdatedGpi is undefined)

The code:

```
var test = result.UpdatedGpi[0];
```

How can I get access to the UpdatedGpi objects and iterate though them?

Comment: Have you tried updatedGpi with a lowercase u just like in the picture and code you included?

Comment: `result.UpdatedGpi` is not the same as `result.updatedGpi`, JS is case sensitive

Comment: *"converted to JSON for clarity. As you can see there is an array called UpdatedGPI."* Where? i don't seen an `UpdateGPI` array.

Comment: @fredriksapps it was the case, new to javascript! Thanks for the help. also "updatedGpi":[{"GPI":"11000010002105"